# Can I store the Subscriber object on the heap?

Tags: ros, c++, roscpp, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to subscribe to topics dynamically.
This is a simplified version of my current solution:

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<ros::Subscriber> rosSubscriberList;
    void doSubscribe() {
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &whatevercallback);
        rosSubscriberList.push_back(sub);
    }
}
```

Which works, but I was just wondering whether if it is safe to do this.

I believe the subscriber object gets copied to the vector, then gets destructed.
So for a short time there are two subscribers? Also, when the MyClass object gets destructed, does the subscriber in the list gets destructed too?

I was wondering if it would be better to have a vector of type

```
std::vector<ros::Subscriber*>
```

and handle object (subscriber) destruction manually. But then there is a copy in that solution too.

Which one would you suggest?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60241/can-i-store-the-subscriber-object-on-the-heap?/) by [Gabor Juhasz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4450/gabor-juhasz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the rosSubscriberList will also be destroyed with the class and thus all its subscribers.

Using `Subscriber*` in the list would solve that, but:

- You'll get some undestroyable pointers/memory leaks
- You could use shared_ptr here in the list, but still you'd need to copy those out to somewhere.
- Given the list belongs to the class intuitively I'd say that this is the behaviour you'd want. If not, maybe a redesign might be better suited.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gabor Juhasz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4450/gabor-juhasz/) on 2013-04-14**:
Yes, that is the behavior I want.I want to clean up everything when my class gets destroyed. Thanks for explaining.